# error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::vector<_Ty> *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I've got the following when building a graph.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Node
{
private:
  T data;
  Node<T> *link;
  vector<T>  neighbors;
public:
  Node(){neighbors = new vector<T>();};
};

int main()
{
  Node<int> n;
  return 0;
}
```

... which returns the error C2679: binary '=': no operator found...

I'm using VS2010. What's wrong? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `new` operator returns a *pointer* type, but your member variable `neighbors` is not a pointer.  So you're assigning a pointer (the result of `new`) to a non-pointer type.  Your `neighbors` variable needs to be a pointer: `vector<T>* neighbors`.

But I think you're probably misunderstanding the use of `new` here.  You probably shouldn't even use a vector pointer at all.  Just remove the line `neighbors = new vector<T>()`.  The vector object will be automatically initialized and ready for use.

In C++, the `new` keyword allocates and initializes objects on the heap, which then must be freed later using `delete`.  It's preferable to avoid the `new` keyword by simply initializing the object as an automatic variable, like:

`vector<T> neighbors;`

This way, you don't have to worry about memory management, and the vector object will automatically be destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Rookie error... That's why it's good to step away and get a coffee. Thanks, Charles!

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<T>  neighbors;
neighbors = new vector<T>();
```

neighbours is not a pointer.

The whole point of using vectors is not managing the memory explicitly. 
In fact in your node constructor, neighbours is default-initialized, so just don't initialize. Your constructor may look like this:

```
Node(){}
```

So you can just omit it :)